# Sudden spike in FCM HTTP API response latency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am seeing sudden spikes in the response time(time taken to hit the API and getting 200 OK response back) of [FCM HTTP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) API in the last 4 days. Has anyone else also witnessed the same?

I am hitting the endpoint `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` to send push notification.
The response time spikes lasts only for a couple of minutes. Earlier, on average throughout the day response time used to be around 200ms, while recently during the spike, response time goes upto 5sec and then reduces back to an average of 200ms.

Metrics graph for API response time few days back:

[image]

Metrics graph for API response time of today:

[image]

Comment: Yes, sometimes it takes time to get fcm push notification in app end, don't know why.

Comment: Not the app. To get 200 OK from FCM, latency is increasing suddenly.

Comment: This is really a question for firebase support but you can read the relevant documentation for latency https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html as your question does not provide details as to whether the latency is only for your testing or is from a deployed app. you can also record events to see at what point in your code latency is being produced https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html .

Comment: This is not a programming question and Google support would be in a better position to analyze and explain latency http://firebase.google.com/support